# z-index issues for burger menu over video but works with Firefox (mobile version)

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a "simple website" (HTML, CSS, JS), in mobile view, using a burger-menu, with a video Background.

Menu links appear but are inactives if they are located above the  background video, on most of the internet browsers.(but work good on firefox).

https://www.bilenekite.com/en/index.html#

Worked as hard as I can with inspectors on "z-index", "!important", on menus, links, video background, and never found a way to make that links "clickable" when they are located over the background video.

Thanks for your Help

Comment: I don't see where is exactly the issue on the website you provided. Can you explain ?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) (Short answer: No.)

Comment: On the mobile version of the website (just reducing the size of the window to can see the burger menu)    / click on the burger icon, the menu will appear / menu-links are not active when they are above the backgound video.   / the ones out of the video are. Thank you

Comment: @CBroe : thank you for your answer, sorry to not can use proper "pure code speaking about" cause for me there is so many different possibilities to see the problem and how to fix it. If it helps, I promise that if I can understand more the issue and the way to correct it, I will rewrite my question and way to fix for everything to be more useful for everyone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to your css for your video.  This will prevent the video from becoming a click target.

```css
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a9a9a9;
    pointer-events: none; /* add here */
}
```

Comment: This is AMAZING.  Thank you so much for this answer. I will try to rewrite my question so it will be more clear to understand this way to solve